# UISwitch doesn't work on Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: uiswitch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to create a UISwitch laid on mapView_ of Google Maps for my iOS app, but it seems not to work.

In details, I first followed instruction from google, created mapView_, then made it my viewcontroller's view:

```
self.view = mapView_;
```

Then, I created an UISwitch programmatically and added it as a subview:

```
mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 360, 0, 0)];
[mySwitch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[mySwitch addTarget:self
             action:@selector(changeSwitch:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[mapView_ addSubview:mySwitch];
```

But when I touched the switch both in simulator and device, it didn't change its state from ON->OFF or OFF->ON. I even tried different UIControlEvent, such as UIControlEventValueChanged but it didn't work. To make sure that the code should work, I tried on a normal view of a normal test viewcontroller (that means, not using google maps), it worked fine!

Does anyone have any comment about this issue?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Probably the map is eating all the touches events... inside the mapView_ there's a subview with class GMSUISettingsView, try adding the switch to that view, it may work (get the list of subviews with mapView_.subviews, iterate over all of them, and pick the correct one).

Comment: @Raspu:I've tried your suggestion. However, the switch although appears still not doesn't work. Brett's comment below does work. Thanks a lot, I now understand a bit more about GMSUISettingsView :D

Comment: @tqn177: If @Brett´s answer works, please mark it as correct. Glad you learned something, and that you solved your problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work around this issue by adding both the UISwitch and the GMSMapView to a single UIView parent, instead of adding the UISwitch as a child of a GMSMapView. Yes, this means you need to position both the GMSMapView and the UISwitch.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm so new to stackoverflow. I just voted up, didn't notice the accept button. Thanks once more!